# logback xml file not found exception on GCP App engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, logback

I have a Spring boot application. For the logging system, I am using logback. The packaging type is WAR instead of JAR.
To use the logback file, I specified the parameter in `application.properties` as:

```
logging.config=file:./src/main/resources/logback.xml
```

This configuration is working correctly on the local system i.e. it is able to find the logback file and the logs are generated at the specified location. But the problem is that once I deploy this code to GCP App engine, I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /base/data/home/apps/s~location-finder-231303/1.416014753384786654/logback.xml (No such file or directory)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
```

Whereas, the logback file is already bundled in the .war file. Am I missing any configuration? Please advise. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to this document [Configuration Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files)  ,all files relate to WAR file will put into /WEB-INF/ folder.

> A Java application cannot use any classes used to write to the filesystem, such as java.io.FileWriter. An application can read its own files from the filesystem using classes such as java.io.FileReader. An application can also access its own files as "resources", such as with Class.getResource() or ServletContext.getResource().
>
> Only files that are considered "resource files" are accessible to the application via the filesystem. By default, all files in the WAR are "resource files." You can exclude files from this set using the appengine-web.xml file.

So you can either remove the setting logging.config from application.properties (it should read default path in war file) or upload logback.xml and change path to ./WEB-INF/logback.xml. Inside src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml, add a config that points to the new logback.xml file. Ex:

```
<property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml"/>
```

You can get more information in this example [SpringBoot HelloWorld for App Engine Standard (Java 8)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard).

> Out of memory errors
>
> With Spring Boot >= 1.5.6, you may run into out of memory errors on startup. Please follow these instructions to work around this issue:
>
> Inside src/main/resources, adding a logging.properties file with:

```
.level = INFO
```

> Inside src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml, add a config that points to the new logging.properties file.

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes   /logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am able to deploy the application with the above changes. But when I am testing the application on the local machine, the log file is not getting created at all. Earlier when I specified the logback path in application.properties, it was there. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The issue got resolved after moving logback.xml file to the resources folder. Thanks for the input!